# Boolean Operators in Typescript Types

Tags: typescript

What's the canonical way to do boolean comparisons in Typescript types?

I've created the following types to do this, but perhaps there is a canonical or better way that I'm not aware of:

```js
type And<T1 extends boolean, T2 extends boolean> = T1 extends T2 ? T1 extends true ? true : false : false
type Or<T1 extends boolean, T2 extends boolean> = T1 extends true ? T1 : T2
type Xor<T1 extends boolean, T2 extends boolean> =  T1 extends T2 ? T2 extends T1 ? false : true : true
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgEwDwBUCMUIA9gUQZygCMB7EgGwgEM4AaKFAJkxzwUNIurgD4oBeBhmy4CDZgH4hLUeyjAATgFdoUxSqgAuKADMq5fNG16DEAFChIUAGJkAQhkHxk6iLVd8oUAPTf5y80toWxI7ZidEJBNDWmiIPl9dfUMLcGD7AGYBWEjXWOT4r0S41KsQuwAWbOcogvcAz2KCs1LoAHkFVGFWMU5KGnomGTYOMn7ebPRhsVcoKSntJlabMkcoDqQ8jy8fP1dlkPD1zrj80wS-EqCVkizBDby4xr2Ag7Iq+5O67d3-FRbrgANEidKYiEbEMbcQbMcG9KE0PiCaRwuRDeawnpojBSOJaP5GAnLQFrYGdLYNHZNUzEo5k2qmM6GC5JGlAu5QemPArPIlAj6ckEMmI-RL7FpmIA)

Comment: For quick boolean checks I don't see a problem with this and I doubt there's a more straightforward way. Note that you could pass `true | false` (=`boolean`) as a generic argument too but that cannot be prevented without overkill solution.

Comment: @Behemoth - thanks for the comment - I thought that may be true.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "canonical" here?  If you mean "part of the language or its documentation" then someone can just answer "no".  If you mean "conventional practice of TS users" then I'm worried this is just an opinion question since it seems to be subjective.  Please [edit] to clarify how we can tell if someone's answer is objectively correct and not just an opinion

Comment: @jcalz, thanks I think that answers the question - No - and so my solution is an acceptable way to proceed - i.e. I'm not committing some egregious error or doing something stupid by doing it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "canonical" implementation of these type operations, as they are not provided in the standard library.  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#31579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31579) to have such operations in the language, but for now there is no such implementation and if you want one you'll need to write your own.

As for whether or not there is a "better" way to do it than yours, that depends somewhat on the use case and largely on opinion.  I certainly don't know of any overwhelmingly common approach of doing this that differs from yours.